# Question on neural network matlab code

Tags: matlab

Hi i found this code somewhere with little info with it.
it's suppose to be a backpropagation neural network code.
but it seem to be lacking of something like weight and bias.
is the code correct? is it test-while-train backpropagation neural network?
thanks

```
    % --- Executes on button press in pushbutton6.

    %~~~~~~~~~~~[L1 L2 1];first hidden layer,second & output layer~~~~~
    layer = [11 15 1];
    myepochs = 30;
    attemption = 1; %i;
    mytfn = {'tansig' 'tansig' 'purelin'};

    %~~~~~~load data~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    m = xlsread('D:\MATLAB\datatrain.csv');   

    %~~~~~~convert the data in Matrix form~~~~
    [row,col] = size(m);          

    P = m(1:row,1:10)';


    T1 = m(1:row, col)';   % target data for training...last column


    net = newff([minmax(P)],layer,mytfn,'trainlm');  %nnet 
     net.trainParam.epochs = myepochs;   % how many time newff will repeat the training
     net.trainParam.showWindow = true;
     net.trainParam.showCommandLine = true;
     net = train(net,P,T1);  % start training newff with input P and target T1

     Y = sim(net,P);   % training

     save 'net7' net;


   % --- Executes on button press in pushbutton4. 

   %~~~~~~load data~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    mt = xlsread('D:\MATLAB\datatest.csv');  

    %~~~~~~convert the data in Matrix form~~~~
    [row1,col1] = size(mt);     
    Pt= mt(1:row1,1:10)';
    Tt = mt(1:row1, col1)';  

    load 'net7' -mat;
    Yt= sim(net,Pt); 

     %~~~~~~~final result of the neural network~~~~~~~~
    [r,c]=size(Yt);
    result=Yt(c);


    if result>0.7
        error=1-result;
        set(handles.edit39,'String','yes')
        set(handles.edit40,'String',num2str(error))
        set(handles.edit41,'String','Completed')
        data1=[num2str(result) ];   
        fid = fopen('D:\MATLAB\record.csv','a+'); 
        fprintf(fid,[data1,'\n']);
        fclose(fid);


    else
        set(handles.edit39,'String','no')
        set(handles.edit40,'String',num2str(result))
        set(handles.edit41,'String','Completed')
        data1=[num2str(result) ];           
        fid = fopen('D:\MATLAB\record.csv','a+'); 
        fprintf(fid,[data1,'\n']);
        fclose(fid);
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct. Neural network weights and biases are stored inside `net` structure, you can access them via `net.IW` and `net.LW` structures. Biases are stored inside `net.b`. This code train a network using inputs `P` and targets `T1`, splitting them in training, testing and validations subsets used during training. Check the documentation for further information about training procedure.

Comment: i understand about training then testing. i'm doing image recognition system using gui. let say i already have 300 image parameter for training store in traindata.csv. then i want to test 100 image. what i did is, i load 1 image then execute this code and repeat it until 100 image is tested. can i do that? is it correct? i have a doubt about that because it looks like test-while-training neural network. is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure to have understood correctly. Well, if you have something like traindata.csv, you can have similarly a file like testdata.csv, isn't it? Then you can use the function sim in order to test your trained network on new testing data...

Comment: i'm using gui to implement this recognition system. after all the train data are saved in the datatrain file, i use this code to to test an image. when i test one image, the answer is yes. but when i test the same image again, the answer is no. why it keep changing when the same image is tested again?

Comment: Is the code the one you pasted above? If you run twice the same code you have different results? Or what?

Comment: i use the code i pasted above. i test the same image twice. the results are different. why is that?

Comment: did you use the entire code from train and test? To test you have to use only the sim function, nothing more. If you repeat all the code you receive different results because neural networks are initialized with random numbers...

Comment: yes. that's why i'm confused. so how do i train the network then test the image? how do i fix the code above?

Comment: Now, it seems correct. The fact is the following: you have to separate the training phase (train function), which gives as output a trained network (net), from the testing phase, which evaluates the performance of a single network (net) on a particular dataset.